# Change the laravel hasing mechanism to encrypt and store the password in users table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

As laravel uses its own mechanism to encrypt and save the password in users table. But i want to change the password encryption mechanism and want to write my own, also the two inbuilt function of laravel authentication should work according to my my password encryption mechanism

> check() and attempt()

Anyone please tell me how to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the laravel authentication with a custom authentication

I had built my laravel project and then had a task to replace the larevel default authentication with a custom authentication module
I could not find any post that could help me fix this issue and had to refer to many articles . There fore i decided to make a post on how this could be done So as to help any one else facing the similar issue.

1.**Files needed to be modified** :

a) **config/auth.php** :
Replace your eloquent driver with your custom driver

```
return [


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Authentication Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
| This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
| attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

// 'driver' => 'eloquent', 

'driver' => 'custom',

    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => 'App\User',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/

'table' => 'user',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Reset Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You can also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'password' => [
    'email' => 'emails.password',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
],
```

];

b) **config/app.php**:
Add your custom provider to the list of providers 'App\Providers  \CustomAuthProvider',

2.**Files needed to be added**
a. **providers/CustomAuthProvider.php**:
Create a new Custom Provider that uses the custom driver that was defined earlier

```
use App\Auth\CustomUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomAuthProvider extends ServiceProvider {


/**
* Bootstrap the application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function boot()
{

    $this->app['auth']->extend('custom',function()
    {

        return new CustomUserProvider();
    });
}

/**
* Register the application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function register()
{
    //
}


}
```

b. **Auth/CutomerUserProvider.php**
  This class will replace the eloquentUserProvider and where all house keeping procedrues can be initiated (after login / before logout) .

```
namespace App\Auth;
use App\UserPoa; use Carbon\Carbon; 
use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser; 
use   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;

class CustomUserProvider implements UserProvider {

/**
* Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
*
* @param  mixed $identifier
* @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
*/
public function retrieveById($identifier)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveById() method.


    $qry = UserPoa::where('admin_id','=',$identifier);

    if($qry->count() >0)
    {
        $user = $qry->select('admin_id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')->first();

        $attributes = array(
            'id' => $user->admin_id,
            'username' => $user->username,
            'password' => $user->password,
            'name' => $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name,
        );

        return $user;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
* Retrieve a user by by their unique identifier and "remember me" token.
*
* @param  mixed $identifier
* @param  string $token
* @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
*/
public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveByToken() method.
    $qry = UserPoa::where('admin_id','=',$identifier)->where('remember_token','=',$token);

    if($qry->count() >0)
    {
        $user = $qry->select('admin_id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')->first();

        $attributes = array(
            'id' => $user->admin_id,
            'username' => $user->username,
            'password' => $user->password,
            'name' => $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name,
        );

        return $user;
    }
    return null;



}

/**
* Update the "remember me" token for the given user in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
* @param  string $token
* @return void
*/
public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
{
    // TODO: Implement updateRememberToken() method.
    $user->setRememberToken($token);

    $user->save();

}

/**
* Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
*
* @param  array $credentials
* @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
*/
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.
    $qry = UserPoa::where('username','=',$credentials['username']);

    if($qry->count() >0)
    {
        $user = $qry->select('admin_id','username','first_name','last_name','email','password')->first();




        return $user;
    }
    return null;


}

/**
* Validate a user against the given credentials.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
* @param  array $credentials
* @return bool
*/
public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
{
    // TODO: Implement validateCredentials() method.
    // we'll assume if a user was retrieved, it's good

    if($user->username == $credentials['username'] && $user->getAuthPassword() == md5($credentials['password'].\Config::get('constants.SALT')))
    {

        $user->last_login_time = Carbon::now();
        $user->save();

        return true;
    }
    return false;


}

}
```

UsePoa (This is my model for the admin table): This is a Model class that i created for my admin table .It implements Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class UserPoa extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {

use Authenticatable;
protected $table = 'admin';
protected $primaryKey  = 'admin_id';
public $timestamps = false;

}
```

3.**Files need to know about** **Guard.php**
 This is the class that will call your User Provider depending on what is defined in the driver. Originally it used to be the EloquentUserProvider .But in this case I have replaced it with the CustomUserProvider. Below is how the methods in the CustomUserProvider are called by the Guard.

1 . Login :
  A. retrieveByCredentials is called to check if the user exists.
  B.ValidateCredentials is called to verify if the username and password are correct .
*Note*: The object that was produced in the retrieveByCredentials is sent to the ValidateCredentials and therefore no second db access is required.

2. Authenticate a page: Whenever an attempt is made to see if a user has been logged in:  retrieveById($identifier) is called.

Logout with remember me setup the method updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token) will be called.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: yeah, you are right. thank you for your valuable suggestion.